# 90's-2000's TV show that involving time travel, contains an episode where a boy and his sister(?) look for their father in ancient Rome/Greece

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have been looking for the name of a TV show I saw an episode of back in the late 90's or the early 2000's.

It was about a boy and a girl (I think she was his sister) looking for his (their) dad. The episode I saw was set in either Rome or Greece (back in time), and there where people wearing togas.

Comment: It very remotely remembers me of a Doctor Who episode set in Pompeii, but Donna Noble is not the Doctor's sister and that episode aired in the mid/late 2000's not in the 90ies.

Comment: Would it be by any chance [MythQuest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273374/) ?

Comment: I think it was thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this picture ([source](http://epguides.com/MythQuest/)) looks familiar then I believe it was [*MythQuest*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273374/).

[image: boy and girl in a striped sweater looking at a screen]

> Matt Bellows scanned a strange and rare artifact, the Gorgos stone to add to his Cyber Museum. In doing so, the stone disappeared into the myth worlds and the evil God, Gorgos was released wanting revenge on the Gods that trapped him in the stone, by way of erasing and changing the myths. Matt entered the world of the myths to stop him. Matt's two teenage children, Alex and Cleo figured out what happened and are searching for their father. Each time they touch the Cyber Museum screen, they are taken directly into the myth and take on the persona of a person of that time, eg Orpheus. Together, they search for their father, learning more and more about the ancient myths, learning about themselves as well.

Comment: You can almost smell the back bacon and Molson's in that picture.